# round robin implementation

Tags: c++, algorithm, round-robin

A computer processor is given N tasks to perform (1 ≤ N ≤ 50,000). The i-th task requires Ti seconds of processing time (1 ≤ Ti ≤ 1,000,000,000). The processor runs the tasks as follows: each task is run in order, from 1 to N, for 1 second, and then the processor repeats this again starting from task 1. Once a task has been completed, it will not be run in later iterations. Determine, for each task, the total running time elapsed once the task has been completed.
Input

The first line of the input contains the integer N, and the next N lines contain the integers T1 through TN.
Output

Output N lines, the i-th of which contains an integer representing the time elapsed when task i has been processed.

Example

**Input:**
5
8
1
3
3
8

**Output:**
22
2
11
12
23

The second task is completed during the first iteration, finishing 2 seconds in. On the third iteration, the third and fourth tasks complete at 11 seconds and 12 seconds, respectively. Finally, on the eighth iteration, the first and last tasks complete at 22 seconds and 23 seconds, respectively.

what cud the approach??

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int n;
cin>>n;
int a[n];
int total=0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{cin>>a[i];total+=a[i];}
int b[n];
int j=0;
for(int i=0;i<total;i++)
{
        while(a[j%n]==0) j++;
        a[j%n]-=1;
        if(a[j%n]==0) b[j%n]=i+1; j++;
}
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
cout<<b[i]<<endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

but this not getting accepted on spoj...

Comment: I'd reject it based solely on your indent style (or lack thereof).  But eh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, as Chakradar Raju said, to emulate the whole procedure is not an good way to implement the job for its huge range. And you need to use types that has wider range than int, for example something like long long which is a 64bit int.

And then try to find a good algorithm to work it out. I'll provide a method, and wish it work.

Every time, we consider a task numbered i, and when it comes to the last second of ith task, all the tasks shorter than it has finished. We only need to sum their cost up. For the tasks not shorter than ith task, we assume the ith task takes Ti seconds. The tasks not shorter than it and the ith task itself both work for (Ti - 1) seconds, and for their own (Ti)th of processing, only the tasks before the ith task works. Sum them up, and you'll get the answer.

Take the sample as an example:

For the 1st task, it takes 8 seconds, and the tasks shorter than it has 1 + 3 + 3 = 7 seconds, then it takes 7 seconds for it and the 5th task, so the value is 7 * 2 = 14 seconds. Then there's no task before ith task, so we only need to add 1 second for the 1st task itself. The result is 7 + 14 + 1 = 22

Maybe it's not clear enough, let's look at the 3rd task, it takes 3 seconds, and only 1 task is shorter than it(the second one which takes 1 second). And all the left tasks take the 3 - 1 = 2 seconds, it's 4 * 2 = 8 seconds. Finally, there's only one task left before it, so only it runs the 3rd time. We add it and the 3rd time processing itself. The result is 1 + 8 + 1 + 1 = 11 seconds.

When coding, you need to remember the sequence number of a task and sort them by their processing time. Then all the tasks short then them are before it. The left job is a linear time processing, and the sort takes O(nlogn) time complexity, which is fast enough to finish the job.

Comment: Maybe there's something not clearly. It's just divided the job into 3 parts, first is the sum of time value smaller than the current time cost(sort and you'll get it with summing up the elements smaller than it). The second job is to sum up the tasks not smaller than the current one, and plus (Ti - 1)seconds for each(the number is n - the first step's count). Finally, you need to get the number of elements before i and their cost is not smaller than ith cost, it's the most difficult part, you can obtain it with a sorting tree or such kind of data structure which operates O(logn) each time.

Comment: Take the 4th number as an example:

We sort the sequence, and with its initial sequence(on the second line):
1 3 3 8 8
2 3 4 1 5
Then sum up the first 3 numbers, it's 1 + 3 + 3 = 7, and for the last 2 numbers, they both run 3 - 1 = 2seconds, so plus 2 * 2 = 4.

The number of tasks before it and cost longer equals the number of 3(4 - 1 for removing itself) minus number of tasks before not longer than itself(3), and it's 3 - 2 = 1, so add 1 to your result, finally it's 7 + 4 + 1 = 12.

For the final step, only need to insert a node into a sorting tree, and count what you need.

Answer (score 2):

First you should understand that limit of int in C/C++ in SPOJ or any g++ compiler, is 2^31, which is a little more than 10^9, so adding 50,000 times 10^9 will make it around 5*10^13, which your total variable can't hold.

Even if the above mentioned problem is rectified, your program wont run in any feasible time.  Even the latest processors can only process upto some constant times 10^9 instructions per second. But your program might need more time than that to complete execution. (I cant exactly say how much time it'll take, but to give a approximate idea, it'll surely take more than 50,000 seconds in worst case, which is almost 13 hours)

Whenever you're submitting a solution to any problem in SPOJ you've to keep these constraints in your mind.